# How to define a bind variable called "1" in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have a application that has been written using bind variables called: 1, 2, 3..
I want to exercise the execution plans stored in sql_area, and use the same text for execute the query in sqlplus

By example:

`select  * from dual where dummy=:1;`

How can I define "1" as a bind variable in sqlplus ?

`var 1 varchar2(1); doesn't work.`

It doesn't recognize "1" as a variable name.

Comment: I am assuming that when you say "It doesn't recognize "1" as a variable name." that you mean you have tried `VARIABLE "1" VARCHAR2(1);` and it does not work? Or were the quotes in that sentence just misleading?

Comment: I read the term "bind variable", but saw the attempt at: `var 1 ...` and assumed the OP might just want a variable named "1".  I'll wait for clarification.

Comment: MT0: I have tried variable "1" varchar2(1); too. It didn't work.

Jon Armstron: I want a variable named 1, without quotes.

Comment: @joseyluis yup, that's an old problem, I had this problem too, so I use own scripts for that

Comment: Just read my answer and a comment to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that's annoying, but you can wrap your query into anonymous PL/SQL block (script) like this:

```sql
SQL> exec execute immediate 'select count(*) cnt from dual where :1=dummy' using 'x';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select sql_id from v$sqlarea a where sql_text like 'select count(*) cnt from dual%';

SQL_ID
-------------
8y7sav2n21055

1 row selected.

SQL> ed tests/run_sql.sql

SQL> !cat tests/run_sql.sql
declare
  vsql clob;
begin
  select sql_fulltext into vsql from v$sqlarea a where a.sql_id='&1';
  execute immediate vsql using &2;
end;
/

SQL> @tests/run_sql.sql 8y7sav2n21055 123

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

[image]

Btw, [SqlCl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html) has another much easier workaround: use `alias` for it:

```sql
SQL> alias sel1=select :1 from dual;
SQL> sel1 123

:1
----------------------------------------------------
123
```

Comment: + of course, you can use dbms_sql instead of `execute immediate` if you want.

Comment: Not the ideal solution in sqlplus, because you can't use explain and other commands, but it is clear that is a limitation in sqlplus.

Shocked that Oracle hasn't provided a solution for this common problem. I will try the SqlCl workaround.

Comment: You can use `explain plan for... ` in `execute immediate ` the same way, since that is also an sql command

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this

```
VARIABLE in VARCHAR2(10)
EXEC :in := 'X';
EXEC EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from dual where dummy=:1' USING :in;
```

If you want to get a result use this

```
VARIABLE in VARCHAR2(10)
VARIABLE out VARCHAR2(10)
EXEC :in := 'X';
EXEC EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ''hello ''||dummy from dual where dummy=:1' INTO :out USING :in;
PRINT out
```

Comment: Thanks. It has been suggested in other answers. I will try it,, altough it's a bit annoying to have to do this for ever sql.

I am not sure it is more simple to rename all bind variables.